# TimerQueue undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a C++ project in Microsoft Visual C++, and I have included windows.h. But I'm getting undeclared identifier errors when using CreateTimerQueueTimer, DeleteTimerQueueTimer and WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD.

As long as I have seen, they should be all declared into windows.h, so I don't understand the problem.

Also, I have other winapi functions being used without problem in the same file, e.g. CreateProcess, so I suppose libraries are installed correctly.

Any help?

Comment: From reference doc for [`CreateTimerQueueTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx) which may help: To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0500 or later.

Comment: I have tried that before and nothing changed

Comment: What version of Visual C++ and/or Platform SDK are you using?  (Really old versions don’t have the declarations you need.)

Comment: @BrianNixon I'm using Visual C++ 6.0 over a windows XP machine

Comment: VS6 predates Windows 5.00 (Windows 2000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting “undeclared identifier” errors because you are using Visual C++ 6, and its Platform SDK headers (from 1998) predate the introduction of the timer-queue functions.

[Versions of the SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_SDK#Versions) that still work with Visual C++ 6 are no longer available for download from the Microsoft Download Center, though direct links to original files still work (see Hans Passant’s comment below), or they can be ordered [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=48615).

Comment: Feb 2003 is the last one that can still work with VC6.  This post has links that still work: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssdk/thread/83205c43-ef46-447d-ae54-92bbeb543c38